# Command to list word completions

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I once found a built-in command that would take a prefix as an argument and return all words that could complete that word. So for example,

```
>> COMMAND cali
California
calibrate
calibration
........
```

of course it would list a lot more words, in alphanumerical order. It was really useful, and optionally took a file other than the default to look in.

I'm *not* just trying to produce this behavior: there are obviously a million ways to use `grep`, `sed`, `awk`, `perl`, or `INSERT TURING-COMPLETE LANGUAGE HERE` to get this. I'm looking for the command.

Unfortunately it's hard to google something when you don't remember the name, but while it might not have been POSIX standard it was definitely a very common Linux utility, does anyone know what this was called?

Answer (score 3):

Found it: it's called [`look`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_look.htm), and it seems to have been around Unix since V7. (The man page is dated 1993!)

It does a binary search on the optional second argument to find all matches, defaulting to `/usr/share/dict/words`.

Answer (score 1):

Not really a builtin command, but there is `/usr/share/dict/*` and `grep`:

```
$ grep -i '^Cali' /usr/share/dict/words
Caliban
Calibanism
caliber
calibered
calibogus
calibrate
calibration
calibrator
calibre
Caliburn
...
```

Comment: yeah, but I definitely found a builtin command on my CentOS machine. I think it had some requirements for the dictionary (such as that it be ordered) that made me think it was much more optimized than a regex